# How to extending config in view

Tags: python, configuration, pyramid

I have an external package that installs (pip install) in `venv` with my pyramid project. And I want extending config in the view. The `client.include.my_pack` have this function adding router:

```py
def includeme(config):
    config.add_route('my_url_view', url)
```

This package should be used in multiple projects and I want to connect it in only one place in the project.

I try connect it:

```py
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.config import Configurator

config = Configurator()
config.include('client.include.my_pack')
config.scan()


@view_config(route_name='my_url_view', request_method='POST', renderer='json')
def home(request):
    pack = request.validated['expected']
    return pack
```

But this code raise exceptions:

```py
pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationExecutionError: <class 'pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationError'>: No route named expected found for view registration.
```

How can I add route in the display instead of __ init __.py project file?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is "No route named expected found for view registration". Your examples talk about a route named "my_url_view", not "expected". I suspect you have another view referencing a route that is not defined? I don't see anything wrong with your pasted code.